# Changing parts of a string with '#'

Tags: python, string

Wanted to see if I'm going in the right direction. I have to change everything but the last four characters of a string into #. I've got two ideas so far.

First one:

```
def maskify(cc):
   cc = raw_input("Enter passcode: ")
   n = len(cc)
   cc.replace(cc[0:n-4], #)  # this one gives me the unexpected EOF while parsing error
```

Second one (I think this one's closer because it supposedly needs an algorithm):

```
def maskify(cc):
   cc = raw_input("Enter passcode: ")  
   n = len(cc)
   for i in range (0, n-4):  # i think a for loop would be good but i don't know how i'm going to use it yet
      cc.replace(                  #not entirely sure what to put here
   pass
```

Comment: an example would be better

Comment: Note that the string literal `'#'` is not the same as the character `#` which, as you are clearly aware, **starts an inline comment**.

Comment: @jonsharpe thanks for that, missed it earlier

Comment: If a passcode has 4 or fewer characters, would you want it displayed or hashed? I would suggest hashed, otherwise the passcode would be completely known.

Comment: Good question @MartinEvans, but we don't want zhangyi changing the specs now that so many answers have been submitted. Let's just assume that the user has been told to enter a passcode of sufficient length. :)  Of course, if we knew at the outset that the passcode was guaranteed to be of length >=4 it would've made the coding a little simpler...

Answer (score 3):

```
cc = raw_input("Enter passcode: ")
cc = ''.join(('#' * (len(cc) - 4), cc[-4:]))
```

Comment: `raw_input()` returns a `str`, so your 2nd line is redundant.

Comment: Instead of `cc[len(cc) - 4:]` you can do `cc[-4:]`. And then you can get rid of the `if` test because `n * '#'` creates an empty string if n<= 0.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following?

```
def maskify() :
    cc = input("Enter passcode: ")
    mask = '#'*(len(cc)-4)
    return mask + cc[-4:]
```

I'm not sure how the flow of the rest of your program works, but I doubt whether you should be prompting for raw_input inside of this function. You can decide that depending on your needs. The alternative would look something like this:

```
def maskify(cc) :
    return '#'*(len(cc)-4) + cc[-4:]

myInput = input("Enter passcode: ")
maskedInput = maskify( myInput )
```

- NB: python2 uses `raw_input` instead of `input`

Comment: tried it just now. got rid of the EOF error but got a 'raw_input is not defined' error instead. thanks tho, didn't know you could do the '#'*(len(cc)-4) when changing parts of a string

Comment: which version of python? In python3, `raw_input` was changed to `input`

Comment: python3, forgot i wasn't using my older version anymore sorry

Comment: Yeah, putting `input()`/`raw_input()` inside a function like that is generally considered to be bad design.

Comment: question for future reference: why is it bad design?

Comment: @zhangyi: It's generally good policy to handle user input in the outermost parts of your code (when practical) rather than doing it in the inner parts of your code. I like to think of my user input routines as border guards that only let good input into the inner sanctum of my code. Users are unpredictable critters and there's no telling what mischief they'll get up to. :)

Comment: @PM 2Ring good point, especially since our instructors get really creative when they test our codes lol

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the first example is that the `#` is unquoted. You need to change it to `'#'` otherwise it is parsed as the start of a comment and the enclosing parenthesis is a part of that comment. Although, this will only fix the parsing error.

The problem with strings is that you can't change characters inside of them (they are [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)). A common way to get around this is to create an array of the string, change the characters you want to change and then convert the array back to a string (often using `''.join(character_array)`). Try that!

Answer (score 1):

The following solution makes the assumption that this would have a security type use, as such passcodes of 4 or fewer characters should just be hashed, otherwise someone would know the whole passcode.

```
def maskify(cc):
    if len(cc) < 9:
        split = [0,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4][len(cc)]
    else:
        split = len(cc) - 4

    return "#" * split + cc[split:]

for length in range(1,12):
    test = string.lowercase[:length]
    print "%s > %s" % (test, maskify(test))
```

Giving the following results:

```
a > #
ab > ##
abc > ###
abcd > ####
abcde > ####e
abcdef > ####ef
abcdefg > ####efg
abcdefgh > ####efgh
abcdefghi > #####fghi
abcdefghij > ######ghij
abcdefghijk > #######hijk
```

If the short hash is not required, then simply change the array as follows to get the other results:

```
def maskify(cc):
    if len(cc) < 9:
        split = [0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4][len(cc)]
    else:
        split = len(cc) - 4

    return "#" * split + cc[split:]
```

Giving:

```
a > a
ab > ab
abc > abc
abcd > abcd
abcde > #bcde
abcdef > ##cdef
abcdefg > ###defg
abcdefgh > ####efgh
abcdefghi > #####fghi
abcdefghij > ######ghij
abcdefghijk > #######hijk
```

Answer (score 0):

The string literal '#' is not the same as the character # which starts an inline comment.

```
def maskify(cc):
   cc = raw_input("Enter passcode: ")  
   mask = '#'*(len(cc)-4)
   return mask + cc[-4:]
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work, for two reasons. Firstly, Python strings are immutable, so you can't change them in-place: you have to assign the return value of `.replace()` to `cc`. Secondly, by default `.replace()` does multiple replacements; eg see what it does to `flipflop`. You can fix that by passing the optional _count_ argument to [.replace()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). In future, _please_ test code before submitting.

Comment: That _does_ work. But now your answer is essentially a duplicate of the one posted earlier by [bebop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31472879/4014959), apart from the added info about properly quoting string literals.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little change to your own code:

```
cc = raw_input("Enter passcode: ")  
n = len(cc)
c=""
for i in range(0, n-4):  # i think a for loop would be good but i don't know how i'm going to use it yet
    c+="#"               #not entirely sure what to put here
cc= c+cc [-4:]
print cc
```

**output:**

```
Enter passcode: kased
#ased
```

Comment: almost. tried it with a longer input and it went something like:

Enter passcode: text here
#here
##here
###here
####here
#####here

it's supposed to just return '#####here'

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned `#` starts a comment. If you want a string containing a hash you need to do `'#'`.

As André Laszlo mentioned, Python strings are immutable, so it's *impossible* for a string operation to change a string's content. Thus the `str.replace()` method can't change the original string: it needs to create a new string which is a modified version of the original string.

So if you do

```
cc = 'cat'
cc.replace('c', 'b')
```

then Python would create a new string containing `'bat'` which would get thrown away because you're not saving it anywhere.

Instead, you need to do something like

```
cc = 'cat'
cc = cc.replace('c', 'b')
```

This discards the original string object `'cat'` that was bound to the name `cc` and binds the new string `'bat'` to it.

---

The best approach (AFAIK) to solving your problem is given in bebop's answer. Here's a slightly modified version of bebop's code, showing that it handles short strings (including the empty string) correctly.

```
def maskify(s) :
    return '#' * (len(s) - 4) + s[-4:]

alpha = 'abcdefghij'
data = [alpha[:i] for i in range(len(alpha)+1)]

for s in data:
    print((s, maskify(s)))
```

**output**

```
('', '')
('a', 'a')
('ab', 'ab')
('abc', 'abc')
('abcd', 'abcd')
('abcde', '#bcde')
('abcdef', '##cdef')
('abcdefg', '###defg')
('abcdefgh', '####efgh')
('abcdefghi', '#####fghi')
('abcdefghij', '######ghij')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all strings are immutable(they can't be changed) once created--so you can't change the value of cc with **replace()**. To change all parts of the string except the last four, do this:

```
def doso(text):
  assert len(str(text))>4, 'Length of text should be >4'
  ctext=str(text).replace(str(text)[:(len(str(text))-4)],'#'*(len(str(text))-4)) 
  print(ctext)

>>>doso(123) prints 'Length of text should be >4' because len(text)== 3 which is what we expect
```

Hovever,

```
 >>>doso(12345678) prints #####6789 which is exactly what we expect
```

Note: Doing **'#' * (len(str(text))-4))**  accounts for the number of characters we want to replace

Answer (score 0):

```
# return masked string
def maskify(cc):

    maskify = cc
    maskifyL= len(maskify) - 4

    char = ""
    a=0

    if maskifyL <= 2:
       c2 = cc
    else:
        for a in range(maskifyL):
            char += "#"
            a += 1
        c2 = maskify.replace(maskify[:maskifyL], char, maskifyL)

    return c2
```